# Product of squence with factorial. Where did division by "missing" terms in the denominator come from?

Tags: products

$\displaystyle\Pi_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{i}{i+4}}=\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{6}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n}{n+4}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot n}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+4)}=\frac{n!}{\frac{(n+4)!}{\color{red}{4!}}}=\frac{n!\cdot4!}{(n+4)!}$

Why did it suddenly divide by $\color{red}{\textrm{factorial of } 4}$ during the transformations? If you think about it, the factorial of 4 is "missing" in the denominator due to the characteristics of the sequence. However, mathematically this action still makes sense. Please explain why the division took place, I thought about it myself but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: You have given the reason with the "missing factorial". $\frac{(n+4)!}{4!}$ is the product of the integers from, $5$ to $n+4$ since the factors upto $4$ are "divided out".

Comment: @Peter As I understand it, there is a relationship: $(n+4)!$ gives division by $4!$ and $(n+3)!$ would be divided by $3!$ because these terms are not factorial. Is it true?

Comment: In the above case yes , since we would have $n$ factors in the denominator , from $4$ to $n+3$. This is by the way nothing else than the reciprocal of the binomial , in the example $\binom{n+4}{4}$ , in the other example it would be $\binom{n+3}{3}$

Comment: @Peter Thanks for help.